# "searchsorted" lookup in pyomo optimization

Tags: python, numpy, pyomo

I have a system that simplifies to the following: a power generation and storage unit are being used to meet demand. The objective function is the cost to produce the power times the power produced. However, the power produced is stratified into bins of different costs, and the "clearing price" to produce power is the cost at the highest bin produced each hour:

```
T = np.arange(5, dtype=int)
produce_cap = 90 # MW
store_cap = 100  # MWh
store_init = 0   # MWh

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=T) # time, hourly

m.produce = pyo.Var(m.T, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=0) # generation
m.store = pyo.Var(m.T, within=pyo.Reals, initialize=0)              # storage
stack = np.arange(10, 91, 20)             # cumulative sum of generation subidivisions
price = np.arange(0.9, 0.01, -0.2)        # marginal cost for subdivision of generation
demand = np.asarray([35, 5, 75, 110, 15]) # load to meet

m.produce_cap = pyo.Constraint(m.T, rule=lambda m, t: m.produce[t] <= produce_cap)
m.store_max = pyo.Constraint(m.T, rule=lambda m, t: m.store[t] <= store_cap)
m.store_min = pyo.Constraint(m.T, rule=lambda m, t: m.store[t] >= -store_cap)
rule = lambda m, t: m.produce[t] + m.store[t] == demand[t] # conservation rule
m.consv = pyo.Constraint(m.T, rule=rule)

# objective
def obj(stack, price, demand, m):
  cost = 0
  for t in m.T:
    load = m.produce[t]
    idx = np.searchsorted(stack, m.produce[t])
    p = price[idx] if idx < len(price) else 1000 # penalty for exceeding production capability
    cost += m.produce[t] * p
  return cost
rule = functools.partial(obj, stack, price, demand)
m.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=rule, sense=pyo.minimize)

# more constraints added below ...
```

The problem seems to be in the objective function definition, using the `np.searchsorted` algorithm. The specific error is

```
Cannot create a compound inequality with identical upper and lower
    bounds using strict inequalities: constraint infeasible:
    produce[0]  <  produce[0] and 50.0 < produce[0]
```

If I try to implement my own searchsorted-like algorithm, I get a similar error. I gather the expression for the objective function that Pyomo is trying to create can't deal with this kind of table lookup, at least how I've implemented it. Is there another approach or reformulation I can consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here.

The root cause is a conceptual misunderstanding of how Pyomo works: the rules for forming constraints and objectives are *not* callback functions that are called during optimization.  Instead, the rules are functions that Pyomo calls to generate the model, and those rules are expected to return *expression* objects.  Pyomo then passes those expressions to the underlying solver(s) through one of several standard intermediate formats (e.g., LP, NL, BAR, GMS formats).  As a result, as a general rule, you should *not* have rules that have logic that is conditioned on the value of a variable (the rule can run, but the result will be a function of the *initial* variable value and will not be updated/changed during the optimization process).

For your specific example, the challenge is that `searchsorted` is iterating over the `m.produce` variable and comparing it to the cutpoints.  That is causing Pyomo to start generating expression objects (through operator overloading).  You are then running afoul of a (deprecated) feature where Pyomo allowed for generating compound (range) inequality expressions with a syntax like "`lower <= m.x <= upper`".

The solution is that you need to reformulate your objective to return an *expression* for the objective cost.  There are several approaches to doing this, and the "best" approach depends on the balance of the model and the actual shape of the cost curve.  From your example, it looks like the cost curve is intended to be piecewise linear, so I would consider either directly reformulating the expression (using an intermediate variable and a set of constraits), or to use Pyomo's "`Piecewise`" component for generating piecewise linear expressions.